# Leaflet polygons sorting

Tags: sorting, leaflet, z-index, polygon

Is there a way, how to z-index polygons using Leaflet nowadays? I am OK when the map is initiated, but when adding new polygons to existing map, I need new polygons to be sorted into existing ones base on their area - so bigger ones will not overlap small ones. I have found this solution:

[Leaflet z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394867/leaflet-z-index)

but it's veeeeery slow, when my map contains bigger amount of features. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about performance of this answer, but you could give it a try:

[GeoJSON Layer Order In Leaflet 0.7.5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/geojson-layer-order-in-leaflet-0-7-5/167904#167904)

The main code is:

```js
// To be called after adding a geoJsonLayer to the map.
function assignZindex(geoJsonLayer) {
    geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer._container.zIndex = layer.options.zIndex;
    });
}

// To be called after assignZindex().
function reOrderVectorLayers() {
    var root = map._pathRoot,
        child = root.firstChild,
        next;

    while (child) {
        next = child.nextSibling;
        if (!next) {
            break;
        }
        if (next.zIndex < child.zIndex) {
            root.insertBefore(next, child);
            if (next === root.firstChild) {
                continue;
            }
            child = next.previousSibling;
            continue;
        }
        child = next;
    }
}
```

It assumes the `zIndex` property is a number defined in `options` of each of your vector (polygon) layer.

As said in comments of that question, if you use Leaflet 1.x, you can now create your own panes that you can order through CSS z-index, and insert each of your vector layer in a specified pane.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly principle of the article I linked in my question - resorting objects using DOM model.

Comment: It is similar indeed in that it uses the DOM to sort your vectors, but the implementation is different. Realize that the DOM sorting is the **only** way to ensure a particular order of SVG elements (hence polygons) in Leaflet 0.x, unless you are ready to modify Leaflet enough so that it behaves like Leaflet 1.x (for creating custom panes).